# How to get last modified date & author from search:search API?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am uploading some documents in Marklogic Server (doc, docx, pdf, txt etc). Now I am building an interface in HTML & XQuery that allows a user to enter a search term and if that matches the contents of any documents, then that document name is displayed in the grid. I am using `search:search` API for searching. Now I also want to show last modified date and author of the document in the grid. Every windows document have last modified date and author property. But how can I get this information from `search:search` API so that I can show these information in the grid ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled the settings "maintain last modified," Marklogic keeps the last modified information in document property fragments. However, this is unrelated to the properties information kept in Windows, which are lost by default when you load them in Marklogic.

If you want to retain the Windows properties data, set up a filter in Information Studio to populate the Marklogic property fragments with the data. Alternately, you could write your own `XSLT` and use `xdmp:document-filter()` to store the data directly in the document.

Once you have loaded your documents and populated them with the properties you need, you can access the data directly if stored in the document, or using `xdmp:document-properties()` if stored in document properties.